# Setup or examples of iOS remote interface mirroring using Firebase

Tags: objective-c, firebase

OK.  I must be missing something.

I'm trying to get two iPads to mirror their interface so that when one user performs UISwipeGesture to push another view, it is replicated on the other device too. I want to actually have the view pushed in real-time and displayed across both instances of the app. I've been reviewing and have test project using Firebase and don't see how to tackle this. However, I've seen native iOS apps that do this using Firebase (not to mention the javascript drawing example).

Does anyone have any good code examples or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase doesn't have any specific primitives for doing application specific synchronization such as interface mirroring. What you'll want to do is model the current state of the interface as JSON into Firebase. So, as parts of the UI change, you save them off to Firebase. Then, you'll also want to setup the complement: when events are fired due to changes from Firebase, update the UI.  The same type of modeling would be required for things like gestures and actions—keep those items saved in Firebase (or, if that doesn't semantically translate easily, keep the side-effects of the actions; e.g. if the swipe causes a button to move positions, save the position of the button in Firebase.)

Concretely, here's an example of keeping two tabs in sync. This is based on the default Xcode project template "Tabbled application".  In it we do a few things:

1. Add a KVO observer for when the tab item changes
2. Setup mirroring reacting from changes from Firebase
3. Actually save the new state of the UI to Firebase

```
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>

#define kFirebase @"https://mirror.firebaseio-demo.com"

@implementation FAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[FSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    // Add KVO observer for when the UI changes so we can eventually synchronize this data to Firebase
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedItem" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];

    // Setup the mirroring of the UI state; when Firebase lets us know the value has been updated, reflect that in the UI
    Firebase* f = [[[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kFirebase] childByAppendingPath:@"selectedIndex"];
    [f observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
      self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = [snapshot.value intValue];
    }];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSUInteger newIndex = [((UITabBar *)object).items indexOfObject:change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]];

    // We've been notified via KVO that the UI has changed, so save the new state to Firebase
    [[[[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kFirebase] childByAppendingPath:@"selectedIndex"] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newIndex]];
}


@end
```

Some things to keep in mind when tackling interface mirroring: suppose a user on one device does an orientation switch—you will readily be able to save this off to Firebase but will have  to make application specific translations on the mirrored side (what if the other device chooses not to rotate their device?).

Comment: I have built your example above and it works! However, I'm still not able to use Firebase with UISWipeGesture or UIBUtton. I have tried to use .selected (self.viewButton1.selected = [snapshot.value intValue]; , but It's not reflecting in the UI.  observeValueForKeyPath:
 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == self.view1Button1 && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"selected"])
    {
        [[[[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kFirebase] childByAppendingPath:@"selectedButtonView1"] setValue:@"1"]

Comment: Gotcha—let me kick around some code and I'll get back to you with a complete example.  Stay tuned!